How can I set environment variables at runtime in SvelteKit?
I'm trying to run playwright tests for my SvelteKit app where I create a new database for each test suite run. I set the environment variables in a test setup file like this:
// e2e/global.setup.ts
import { exec as baseExec } from 'child_process';
import util from 'util';
import { test as setup } from '@playwright/test';
import { uid } from 'uid';

const exec = util.promisify(baseExec);

setup('create new database', async ({}) => {
  // Vite replaces dot notation
  // https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3176
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/dot-notation
  process.env['DATABASE_URL'] = `file:e2e/${uid()}.db`;
  await exec('npm run db:push -- --force');
});

I am able to read process.env in the teardown file, but the tests themselves still use the database url set in my .env file. My database is setup like this:
// src/lib/server/db/index.ts
import { createClient } from '@libsql/client';
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/libsql';
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

if (env.DATABASE_URL == null) {
  throw new Error('DATABASE_URL is not set');
}

const client = createClient({ url: env.DATABASE_URL });

export const db = drizzle({ client, casing: 'snake_case' });

How do I get the tests to use the database created in the setup file?

Is there evidence that setting a new variable via process.env like you do is inherited by the child process?  Because it sounds like adding the new environment variable simply adds it to the current process, and not passed on to the child process.  I checked npmjs.com for the "child_process" package but doesn't exist.

@JoséRamírez child_process is from the node.js standard library (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback). By default it passes process.env to the child process. I can see the database being setup and torn down when I run the tests. The tests just aren't using the test database.

Not sure what files are you showing in your snippets but In SvelteKit the $env/dynamic/private import can only be done in a server environment using a +page.server.js or +layout.server.js file. And those variables are imported from a file that must live in the $lib/server/ directory. Your env variable usage would look something like this:
//$lib/server/test_setup.js

//other imports
import { uid } from 'path/to/uid';

export const DATABASE_URL = `file:e2e/${uid()}.db`

// rest of your test code...

Then in your server you'd do this:
//+layout.server.js or +page.server.js

//other imports
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

const client = createClient({ url: env.DATABASE_URL });

export async function load() {
    return {client: client}
}

And finally in your +page or +layout you'd use it like this:
//+layout.svelte or +page.svelte
    
<script>

// the `data` prop receives the return from the load function
export let data 

console.log(data.client)
</script>   

<h1>{data.client}</h1>

Hope this helps!

I have updated the question with the file paths. The test setup is outside the src folder, which is why I use process.env. Your example test_setup file does not compile. export DATABASE_URL is invalid Javascript

Sorry it was supposed to be export const DATABASE_URL, I edited the response to fix it. If it lives outside of the source, I recently saw a great answer using Vite's meta.glob.import to import multiple modules from the file system into your src/lib/server/db/index.ts, and then set it as an env variable with the process I suggested.

I don't quite understand what you mean by using meta.glob.import. Which file would I use it in? How would I read the env variable?

The approach I thought of was using the meta.glob.import to import the global.setup.ts as a module into your  src/lib/server/db/index.ts. Then use that import to set the dynamic environment variables at runtime in your SvelteKit app via the load function in the +page.server.ts file.

global.setup.ts is for test code only. For normal development, I want to use the DATABASE_URL set in the environment variable. I don't think it makes sense to put test-specfic setup in the src directory

I see, so you don't need to set environments variables at runtime on SvelteKit since you'll be shipping a static variable from the .env file, correct? For what I can infer from your code you should export the DATABASE_URL with the concatenation I put in the answer.  Because of the way that SvelteKit is set up I don't know a way you can run your test completely outside of the /src directory. So even though is not best-practice, the solution would be to use a test that passes within the src and remove it before shipping.

Is there an existing best practice for creating and deleting the test database when using Svelte? I must be way off track if it can't be done with environment variables
